# review test: low quality

Tags: discussion

I am a bit disappointed because I was just told that I had failed a review test. Funny though, I was going to take that one here even before I accepted that one because it was presented to me as the "first answer" of a 10,000+ user...

[This was the question](https://serverfault.com/questions/478559/nginx-rewrite-with-query-string-without-if)

It ends with "Is that the correct way ?". The (fake?) answer which I should have rejected as "very low quality" was: "Yes, that's the correct way.​​"

I have no idea whether this really is the correct way but reviewing isn't about content, is it? If the answer was "No" then it's obvious that it needs some detail. But why should "Yes, that's the correct way.​​", especially by a user with a huge reputation, be a "very low quality answer"? I don't get it. Is this about producing useless text? About "proving" this to be correct (how should that be done anyway)?

Comment: I think this is a valid Meta question, but probably belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com -- they handle the "how SE works" questions.  The "Yes, that's the correct way." answer *was* a real answer at one point, but it has since been deleted.

Comment: That was an actual answer, If you had 10k rep you could see that it was deleted by a mod which is probably what put it into the test queue. Honestly, this whole test queue thing sucks.

Comment: It certainly isn't a high quality answer.  I usually would have used a comment to say something like `yes that is the way`.  Then I probably would have looked very close to see if the question needed to be closed. A question that only had that as a valid answer usually isn't very well written.

Comment: I almost failed this exact test... ;-)

Comment: @Zoredache  While it's not exactly a high quality answer, that's not necessarily the same as an answer deserving a delete vote, a downvote and/or a flag. Like Chris points out in his answer, the review audit system is supposed to providing tests with example that are clear-cut right or wrong, and it's not, due to the current implementation used to select audit material.  Yippie, devops.

Comment: I failed the same thing and others which are equally gray area stuff where I disagreed with this audit systems view of things. For what it's worth, this crap has reduced my motivation to review to zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some of the review audits need work. Most of the audits have high passing scores, no problems.

In some areas we have a failure rate over 50%, and I can see many of them going either way. The audit system was supposed to give clear examples, where anyone with a brain could get it right. That's not the case right now in many of them.

One note, several of the queues only use moderator actions as indications of the "correct" answer. In this question a moderator deleted the Answer, so that was the correct answer here. Moderators can be fickle at times, so I don't completely agree with this basis. Also, unless you went out of your way you couldn't see that there was another answer.

A side note to that last note, moderators have been cracking down on crappy answers. So you have to be very strict with your review else you'll end up on the "wrong" side of an opinion as to whether a post is good enough.

All I can say for now is that they're still tweaking the system and you're not the only one.

Comment: What do you mean by "graded"? Selecting as "this answer should be used for review tests"?

Comment: Rewrote most of my post. See edit.

Comment: I just got one too which looked like it got closed because it was answered by someone promoting a tool they wrote.  However, it had a comment that pointed this conflict of interest out already, and was otherwise a valid answer so I clicked Leave Open.  So this is a beta test right?  Or just wasting peoples time?

Comment: The system is still in "Beta", it's only on the trilogy sites, and only certain audit failures lead to review-bans right now. The Devs are looking at the failure rates, what's causing high failures, etc. They've been taking their time with it, so I wouldn't expect dramatic improvements soon; but they'll get there.

Answer (score 4):

I checked and the system is [working as designed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171900/new-user-with-1-493-reputations-and-more-than-20-badges-possible-or-a-bug). It appears that you should ignore the *'meta'* information and simply review the content.

There is a bug in the system though as the review [immediately before](https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/61898) yours was the OP being presented with their own deleted content.